# How to protect Streaming Key from public?

Tags: rtmp, wowza

I am sending a live RTMP stream from OBS to [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/) Streaming Engine and playing it back in [JW Player](https://jwplayer.com/) on my website. Members of my website will be able to stream to their own "channels".

The only issue is that if a viewer on my website views the source, he/she can access the stream key. If a user gets another users stream key, then they would be able to stream to their channel.

What is a good way to protect this stream key?

Comment: Check the API docs or Google for ways to make an authenticated stream request without the key.  Client asks server for to sign / authenticate request, server supplies one-time token.  Most APIs have this.

Comment: Searched literally all day and couldn't find anything. Lots of streaming platforms implement this. They have a "private" streaming key and I assume a public one. I'm just unsure how to go about this. I figured this would be a common issue, since without password authentication on anyone can push to your RTMP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a module that does a server issued token based authentication. There also exist a free limited version of some commercial modules for similar purpose. Here is an article that shows how to start the work: https://streamtoolbox.com/hello-wowza-module-tutorial